# How to get specific fields values from multiple ManyToOne-related entities with JPQL?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I'm new to JPA, so don't kick me too hard for potentially dumb question, but google didn't give me the answer.

I use PostreSQL database. Let's say I have entity One, which has `ManyToOne` relation with entity Two (List two), and entity Two, in it's turn, has `ManyToOne` relation with entity Three (List three).

All three entities has their own ID field in them.

So with `JPQL` I'm trying to execute the following query:
`"SELECT o.two.ID, o.two.three.ID FROM One o WHERE o.ID = 1 GROUP BY(o.two.ID, o.two.three.ID)"`.

But all I receive is `Internal Server Error`, `SQLGrammarException` and `SQLState: 42803, Character code: 8.`

There is record in pg_log that `o.two.ID` must be specified in `GROUP BY`, but it's already there.

Comment: Not sure by I believe you don't need parenthesis in group by. Might be worth a try. And just noticed you have `o.two.three.ID` in SELECT and `o.three.ID` in GROUP BY. These must match.

Comment: Have you tried without the group by?

Comment: @Narain Mittal Yes, I tried without parenthesis in group by, but it changed nothing.  And sorry, it looks that I've misspelled o.three.ID while writing the question, it's o.two.three.ID actually.  I will fix the question now.

Comment: @Desorder Yes, I tried without group by. When JPA parses the query it doesn't find the table_Three.  In FROM there are only table_One and table_two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution!

All I needed was to add `OneToMany` back relations in my entities, so entity `Two` must be `OneToMany`-related to entity `One` and entity `Three` must be `OneToMany`-related to entity `Two`.

Thanks, everybody!

Comment: Ah, the good old reverse relationship. Mark your answer as correct as well so we know it question has been answered :)